# What are the advantages of doing 100% managed development using C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

What are the advantages (the list of possible disadvantages is lenghtly) of doing **100% managed** development using C++/CLI (that is, compile with [/clr:safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85344whh(VS.80).aspx) which "generates ... assemblies, like those written in ... C#")?  Especially when compard to C# (note [C++/CLI : Advantages over C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886881/c-cli-advantages-over-c) and [Is there any advantage to using C++/CLI over either standard C++ or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297323/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-c-cli-over-either-standard-c-or-c) are mostly about managed/unmanaged interop).

For example, here are a few off the top of my head:

- [C++-style references for managed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181846/how-can-i-get-close-to-non-nullable-types-in-c-today), not as elegant as full blown [non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=non-nullable) references but better than nothing or using a [work-around](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/06/non-nullable-reference-types.aspx).
- templates which are more powerful than generics
- preprocessor (this may be a disadvantage!, but macros can be useful for code generation)
- stack semantics for reference types--automatically calling *IDisposable::Dispose()*
- easier implementation of *Dispose()* via C++ destructor

C# 3.0 added auto-implemented properties, so that is no longer a C++/CLI advantage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886881/c-cli-advantages-over-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++/CLI you can define functions outside of classes, you can't do that in C#. But I don't know if that is an advantage

Answer (score 7):

I would think that the single biggest advantage is the managed/unmanaged interop. Writing pure managed C++/CLI would (to me at least) without interoping with C# or other .Net languages seems like missing the point entirely. Yeah you could do this, but why would you?

If you're going to write pure managed code why not use C#. Especially (like nobugs said) if VS2010 drops IntelliSense support for C++/CLI. Also in VS2008 the IntelliSense for C++/CLI isn't as good the C# IntelliSense; so from a developer standpoint, it's easier to work/explore/refactor in C# than C++/CLI.

If you want some of the C++ benefits you list like the preprocessor, stack semantics and templates, then why not use C++?

Comment: C++/CLI is awful for anything but interop. You hit the nail on the head with the comment of using C# if you wanted to write managed assemblies.

Comment: @Dan, I'm not convinced those alone are sufficient to sweep aside the ease of development and better IDE support of C#

Answer (score 5):

Odd, I like C++/CLI but you listed exactly its features I dislike.  My criticisms:

- Okay.  But accidental use of the hat is pretty widespread, getting the value of the value type boxed without warning.  There is no way to diagnose this mistake.
- Power that comes at a high price, templates you write are not usable in any other .NET language.  If anything, it worsens the C++ template export problem.  The complete failure of STL/CLR is worth pondering too.
- Erm, no.
- This was IMO a serious mistake.  It already is difficult to avoid problems with accidental boxing, as outlined in the first bullet.  Stack semantics makes it seriously difficult for any starting programmer to sort this out.  This was a design decision to placate C++ programmers, that's okay, but the using statement was a better solution.
- Not sure how it is easier.  The GC.SuppressFinalize() call is automatic, that's all.  It is *very* rare for anybody to write a finalizer, but you can't avoid the auto-generated code from making the call.  That's inefficient and a violation of the 'you don't pay for what you don't use' principle.  Add to this that writing the destructor also forces a default finalizer to be auto-generated.  One you'd never use and wouldn't want to be used if you forgot or omitted to use the destructor.

Well, that's all very subjective perhaps.  The death-knell will come with VS2010, it will ship without IntelliSense support for C++/CLI.

Comment: Where are you hearing the VS2010 will drop IntelliSense for C++?

A quick search in Google for "VS2010 IntelliSense c++" comes back with nothing but improvements for IntelliSense.

-1 Until you can prove your statement.

Comment: @Russ - Not for C++, for C++/CLI as clearly stated in my post.  Link: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=477959  Gimme my points back, dammit!

Comment: Although I think I would have prefered something more recent. ( https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=501921&wa=wsignin1.0 ). I'll take it.

+1 for providing evidence.

Comment: argh, Stack overflow says my vote is too old to me changed unless than answer is edited. ( +1 on your comment with proof )

Comment: In normal C++, if a constructor throws, any objects which have been constructed as part of it will have their destructors run.  Does C++/CLI do that?  If so, that would seem to be an advantage over C# which can sometimes make it very difficult to construct class hierarchies which won't leak when a constructor throws.

Comment: This answer illuminated me to some of the obviously infrequently discussed negatives of C++. I would like to suggest [an edit](http://pastebin.com/raw/z5tG9dgM) which would bring the focus of the question into the answer making it much easier to read without scrolling back to the top of the page at each bullet point. Additionally, I think it might be a good idea to elaborate upon the preprocessor point; perhaps comparing the expressive power of the preprocessing language (or rather, lack of) to other text processing languages (e.g. Perl, not that I'd recommend that language) might make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Like others here, I can't think of any general cases where a clear advantage exists, so my thinking turned to situational advantages -- are there any cases where there is an advantage in a particular scenario?

**Advantage:** Leverage the C++ skill set of technical staff in a rapid prototyping scenario.

Let me elaborate ...

I have worked quite a bit with scientists and (non-software) engineers who aren't formally trained programmers. Many of these people use C++ for developing specific modules involving high-end physics/mathematics. If a pure .NET module is required in a rapid prototyping scenario and the skill set of the scientist/engineer responsible for the module is C++, I would teach them a small amount of additional syntax (`public ref`, `^` and `%` and `gcnew`) and get them to program up their module as a 100% managed C++/CLI DLL.

I recognize there are a whole heap of possible "Yes, but ..." responses, but I think leveraging the C++ skill set of technical staff is a possible advantage of C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I agree on what you have mentioned and as an example of preprocessor use point to: [Boost Preprocessor library for generating a set of types based on a list of basic types e.g. PointI32, PointF32 etc. in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222849/boost-preprocessor-library-for-generating-a-set-of-types-based-on-a-list-of-basic)

Answer (score 1):

You can have enums and delegates as generic constraints in C++/CLI, but not in C#.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386194/allow-enum-as-generic-constraint-in-c

There is a library to simulate these constraints in C#.

http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/

Answer (score 0):

One could imagine the following requirements for a hypothetical product:

1. Quick time-to-market on Windows
2. Eventual deploy to non-Windows platforms
3. Must not rely on Mono for non-Windows

In such a scenario, using eg C# for 1 would stymie you on 2 and 3 without a rewrite. So, one could develop in C++/CLI, suitably munged with macros and template shenanigans to look as much like ordinary C++ as possible, to hit reqt 1, then to hit reqt 2 one would need to (a) reimplement said macros and template shenanigans to map to pukka C++ and (b) implement .NET framework classes used in pukka C++. Note that (a) and (b) could be reused in future once done once.

The most obvious objection would be "well why not do the whole thing in native C++ then?"; well maybe there's lots of good stuff in the vast .NET class library that you want to use to get to market asap.

All a bit tenuous I admit, so I very much doubt this has ever been done, but it'd be a fun thing to try out !